# How to Form WebRequest for Multi part Form data and it's Value?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, oauth-2.0, box

I have the Rest API Url `https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token`. To get the Refresh/Access Tokens respectively.

When i try this in `PostMan (Chrome Extension)` Its working fine. Below i have attached the screen shot.

Getting the Access Token Reference : https://developers.box.com/oauth/

[image]

But the same i tried in Code its giving me the `Bad Request Error`.

```
    public string PostToUrl(string url, string data)
    {
        string results = String.Empty;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        results = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return results;
    }

    public override void TestConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
       string json = PostToUrl("https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token", "code=" + Code + "&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" + ClientId + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret);
    }
```

here my question is....

How do i need to form the request for this rest `API call`?
How the Multi Form Data's and values need to be merged to that request?

**Box Request through Post Man:**

[image]

**Box Request from My Code :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the `NameValueCollection` to the Headers. Like Below

```
            var nameValue = new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
                {"client_id", ClientId},
                {"client_secret", ClientSecret},
                {"code", RefreshToken}
            };

            request.Headers.Add(nameValue);
```

Initial Reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124152/authentication-to-box-in-a-c-sharp-desktop-application-using-the-box-windows-sdk/22182612#comment37447780_22182612)

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to compare both request with [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch the differences.

You can also simplify your Rest handling code with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have compared already through fiddler. But i'm not getting how to add those content disposition with form data and its values. i have updated the question